# python tkinter hide the window during widget creation

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a small annoying problem so I come to you to see if you can help to solve it.
I have the following code in Python2.7:

```
# main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('My application')
# create the objects in the main window
w = buildWidgetClass(root)
# size of the screen (monitor resolution)
screenWi = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHe = root.winfo_screenheight()
# now that widgets are created, find the widht and the height
root.update()
guiWi = root.winfo_width()
guiHe = root.winfo_height()
# position of the window
x = screenWi / 2 - guiWi / 2
y = screenHe / 2 - guiHe / 2
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (guiWi, guiHe, x, y))
```

So I create the main window (without any size) I insert widgets inside, then I define the size of the result, and place it in the middle of the screen.

The number of widget in the window may vary, so the resulting size!

So far, so good, it works ! My only problem is that the window first appear in the left top corner of the screen, then repositioned to the center. Not a big deal, but not really professional neither.

So my idea was to hide the main window during the widgets creation time and then make it appearing after having defined the geometry.

So after the first line, I added :

```
root.withdraw()
```

then at the end :

```
root.update()
root.deiconify()
```

but when the window reappear, it wasn't re-sized by the widget and have a size of 1x1 !!
I tried to replace **root.withdraw()** by **root.iconify()**, the window is correctly re-sized but, surprisingly, isn't deiconified at the end !!!

I'm a little bit lost on this ...

Comment: What geometry manager are you using `buildWidgetClass`? Grid or pack?

Comment: grid ! Why is it important ?

Comment: Not very important, but `place` doesn't change the size of the window while `pack` or `grid` does.

Comment: I understood why my window is 1x1 with "withdraw". When in "withdraw", the window is ignored by the window manager and thus not updated ! So even with "root.update" it size is 1x1, then I define the geometry with this values and it's not resized after ... :-(

Comment: I tried to add `root.deiconify()` just before `root.update()` and finding the size of the window and it works ... but I come back a the beginning, the window appear in the top corner and then is moved at the center. Must try it through ssh to see if it's really as ugly as I imagine ...

Comment: I've tried your code and the window appears directly on the center - if there is any reposition, it's almost impossible to notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `root.winfo_reqwidth` instead of `root.winfo_width` may help in your case.

Comment: unfortunately not ! `root.winfo_reqwidth` return 200 when it should be more than 600. As I said, and explained in the tk documentation, when the root window is "withdraw" the window manager ignore it and never update its size

Comment: What is return value of `winfo_width` if you insert `root.update_idletasks()` just before `w = buildWidgetClass(root)`?

Comment: Finally you was right ! During my long and painful tests, I removed the `root.update()`. That the reason apparently why the `root.winfo_reqwidth` didn't returned the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Finally with the input of kalgasnik, I have a working code

```
# main window
root = tk.Tk()
# hide the main window during time we insert widgets
root.withdraw()

root.title('My application')
# create the objects in the main window with .grid()
w = buildWidgetClass(root)
# size of the screen (monitor resolution)
screenWi = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHe = root.winfo_screenheight()
# now that widgets are created, find the width and the height
root.update()
# retrieve the requested size which is different as the current size
guiWi = root.winfo_reqwidth()
guiHe = root.winfo_reqheight()
# position of the window
x = (screenWi - guiWi) / 2
y = (screenHe - guiHe) / 2
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (guiWi, guiHe, x, y))
# restore the window
root.deiconify()
```

Thanks a lot to both of you for your time and your help